# How to make a greasemonkey user script that replaces link

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying all links w/ Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282986/modifying-all-links-w-greasemonkey)

So I need to make user script that redirect one link to an another, but I don't know anything about `javascript`.

I want to replace `www.kaskus.co.id/showpost.php?p=204852850&postcount=11`
with old.`kaskus.co.id/showpost.php?p=204852850&postcount=11`

the difference is only at the front of page adress. And the numbers after php?p= are vary. So in conclusion I want to replace
`www.kaskus.co.id/showpost.php?p=`
with 
`old.kaskus.co.id/showpost.php?p=`

note that I need to redirect the link from that complete adress, not the basic adress which is only the `www.kaskus.co.id`

so can you please make the script? I'd greatly appreciate it :D

Comment: Do you want that **after user clicks** `www.kaskus.co.id/showpost.php?p=204852850&postcount=11`, He should go to `kaskus.co.id/showpost.php?p=204852850&postcount=11` instead?

Comment: Duplicate of [Modifying all links w/ Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3282986/331508), and [How can I rewrite links with JavaScript or jQuery and a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12731801/331508), and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Autoredirect
// @description    Autoredirect
// @include        *Add your page here. wildcards suppoe*
// ==/UserScript==
var a=document.links;
var i;
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
if(a[i].href.match(/www.kaskus.co.id\/showpost\.php\?/))
    a[i].href=a[i].href.replace(/www.kaskus.co.id/,"old.kaskus.co.id");
```

Comment: what a huge waste of regex. what is wrong with `^www`?

Comment: I am also accounting for possibility of having http:// at start. Plus as per his question, he wants to specifically redirect some pages to old. Domain.